# Gmail does not forward auto-archived messages to another account

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

I have configured my current Gmail account to forward mails to another Gmail email. But I notice that the auto-archived messages won't be forwarded.

How can I get all mails forwarded?

Answer (score 1):

Nam,  I once had the same problem with Spam and found that it only worked when I used a negative filter (Doesn't have).

Create a new filter in settings.
`Doesn't have` = Ð (or any other odd character or set of characters that you do NOT expect in  any message)
Click on `Continue`
Check the following categories:
Forward it to:
Never send it to Spam:

Never tried this for auto-archived messages, but you might give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the Auto-Archive menu, you can tick both "Skip inbox" (Auto-Archive) AND the forward to other e-mail.